# $uibModal not working in Angular using es6

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, ui.bootstrap

Portion of my index.html showing i have included angular and angular ui bootstrap both. And they are loading fine , have confirmed that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am injecting 'ui.bootstrap' module in my admin module which is injecting just fine

```
var admin = angular.module('admin', ['ngResource', 'ui.router','ui.bootstrap' ])
.controller('UserController', UserController)
```

This is my controller class where i am injecting $uibModal and getting exception. Could not figure out the reason why...

```
export default class UserController {
// @ngInject
constructor(UserService, $uibModal) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out that i was on angular 1.2 angular ui-bootstrap supports